# Many-state nominal variables modelling

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I was reading about neural networks and found this: 
"Many-state nominal variables are more difficult to handle. ST Neural Networks has facilities to convert both two-state and many-state nominal variables for use in the neural network. Unfortunately, a nominal variable with a large number of states would require a prohibitive number of numeric variables for one-of-N encoding, driving up the network size and making training difficult. In such a case it is possible (although unsatisfactory) to model the nominal variable using a single numeric index; a better approach is to look for a different way to represent the information."

This is exactly what is happening when I am building my input layer. One-of-N encoding is making the model very complex to design. However, it is mentioned in the above that you can use a numeric index, which I am not sure what he/she means by it. What is a better approach to represent the information? Can neural networks solve a problem with many-state nominal variables?

References:
http://www.uta.edu/faculty/sawasthi/Statistics/stneunet.html#gathering

Answer (score 1):

Solving this task is very often crucial for modeling. Depending on a complexity of distribution of this nominal variable it'seems very often truly important to find a proper embedding between its values and `R^n` for some n.

One of the most successful example of such embedding is **word2vec** where the function between words and vectors is obtained. In other cases - you should use either ready solution if it exists or prepare your own by representational learning (e.g. by autoencoders or RBMs).